# MySQL if a row appears twice only display it once, but if it appears n times(which cant be two) then display its name n times?

Tags: mysql

for example:

database:

- Tom
- David
- Tom
- George
- David
- David

after the mysql command these will come out as a result:

- Tom
- David
- George
- David
- David

thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of aggregation and `UNION ALL` like this:

```
SELECT name FROM t GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM t
WHERE name NOT IN
  ( SELECT name FROM t GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
  );
```